# Custom search screen with date range not working in VS Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I created a custom search screen in Visual Studio 2012 LightSwitch based on a Transactions table that has a TransactionDate field. I also added a couple of other fields in my custom search screen that I want to filter.

When LightSwitch generated my page, I immediately edited the query by filling out the necessary WHERE clause with my parameters. I added a BeginDate and an EndDate parameters. LightSwitch generated my screen with the appropriate controls for me to use to filter a corresponding Data Grid on the same screen.

However, when I enter values in the first two fields the Data Grid automatically filters as I tab over to the next field. But when I enter the BeginDate and EndDate the Data Grid does not refresh when I tab away from any of them. Can anyone explain why this is so? For date ranges, do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for what you describe is if the query parameters aren't actually bound to the screen controls. If they're bound correctly, you'll see a line connecting them when either the parameter or the control has been clicked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yann, turned out to be a combination of that and the Auto Execute flag. By the way, I'm currently reading your book. Excellent job! It's helping me learn LightSwitch much faster!

Comment: You're welcome (I could have sworn that I had already replied to this, but the comment doesn't appear). Thanks for the kind words about the book. I'm glad you find it useful.